# how did Asuna move?

Tags: sword-art-online

I know that Kirito didn't die at the end if episode 14 because of his will to fight overthrowing the system. But during the fight with Heathcliff, episode 14, when all players were paralyzed, how did asuna manage to move in front of the sword? Was it the same concept above, or was it because of somthing else?

Answer (score 2):

It was stated to be her willpower. In chapter 23 of first tome of light novel:

> Just to save me, the shy and spoiled Asuna had shaken off the
>   incurable paralysis with her willpower and thrown herself against an
>   attack that was impossible to block.

In terms of game features, it might be some sort of bug, since Kayaba was not expecting thing like this to be possible

> This is really surprising. Isn’t it just like a standalone console RPG
>   scenario? It should have been impossible for her to recover from the
>   paralysis… So things like this really do happen…

I suppose, it was author's idea of willpower and true feelings being able to surpass most limitations, so we probably will not find any more clues.

Answer (score 0):

well If you think about it asuna's will to protect kirito was probably greater than kirito's will to fight so naturally her being able to move was only natural since she was feeling intense emotions.